# Copy elements from a list of pairs to another

Tags: racket

I am new to racket and I am trying to copy the second element of each pair from

`'(("a" . 1) ("c" . 3))`

to

`'(("a" . null) ("b" . null) ("c" .null))`

As you can see in the example I need to copy them based on the first element of the pair. Basically I'm trying to merge them into a single one like this:

`'(("a".1) ("b".null) ("c" . 3))`

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried to match them using assoc and map but i don't really understand how to do it properly. I know that assoc returns the matching pair in a list of the argument you give it. I am trying to replace the pair with the null value with the one with the integer value

Answer (score 0):

Racket lists and cons cells are not mutable. If you want to replace a cons pair in a list then you have to generate a new list. So your `replace` procedure should take an association list as an argument and evaluate to a modified association list. The strategy might be then to cons down the association list until you find the element or hit the end of the list.

Here I use symbols instead of strings, so I can use `eq?` as my predicate:

```
(define (replace alist pair)
  (define target (car pair))
  (define (found? al)
    (eq? (caar al) target))
  (define (rpl al)
    (cond ((null? al)
           (list pair))
          ((found? al)
           (cons pair (cdr al)))
          (else (cons (car al)
                      (rpl (cdr al))))))
  (rpl alist))
```